# Intellij static final collection inspection

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I looked for a IntelliJ inspection, but couldn't find it.

If you take the code snippet below, it is supposed to be a constant, but it is not immutable.

```
private static final Set<MyEventType> TYPES = EnumSet.of(MyEventType.APPROVED,MyEventType.REJECTED);
```

it is perfectly valid to do the following.

`TYPES.add(MyEventType.CANCELED);`

So is there a IntelliJ inspection which would give mi a warning that my collection is not immutable. Usually it is what you want with static final fields.

This would be the correct code:

```
private static final Set<MyEventType> TYPES =  Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(MyEventType.APPROVED,MyEventType.REJECTED));
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant inspection is Settings > Editor > Inspections > Java > Naming conventions > Non-constant field with uppercase name.

That's really all that's wrong with the above. It just happens that you intended the set to be unmodifiable, but `EnumSet.of` is fully documented to return a modifiable set. The convention for "constants" is that the field itself is constant, not the referenced object (compare, for example, the use of LOGGER as a field name: the logger reference is constant, but the logger instance can be modified). Intellij IDEA doesn't (as far as I know; I may be corrected) have an inspection for using uppercase field names for modifiable objects.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ can already identify cases of calling `add` on an immutable collection:

```
private final Set<SessionServerState> ALL_STATES = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.allOf(SessionServerState.class));

ALL_STATES.add(...);
```

[image]

If you expand this tooltip, it comes from the `Constant conditions & exceptions` inspection.

[image]

Comment: I would want it the other way around, I.e., an inspection which tells me I forgot to make collection immutable